# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (83) into shape (84)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

The goal of this part of code is to take a list of dictionaries, get a specific dictionary, use the values of this dictionary to make a list, converting the list into a numpy array, and to do this for all the 3399 dictionaries (len(X)) that I have build in the previous sections of my code. Every step of this process went smoothly, till I got to the last part

```
input_array = np.zeros([len(X),84])
for i in range(0,len(X)):
input_array[i,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict[i].values()))
```

When performing these lines of code, the following error shows up:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (83) into shape (84)
```

Well, the solution seems quite evident, right? Just change the dimensions of the initialized array and everything will be fixed... not quite. Changing the dimensions as follows yields a very strange result that I just can't seem to bypass, no matter what I do or try.

```
input_array = np.zeros([len(X),83])
for i in range(0,len(X)):
input_array[i,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict[i].values()))
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (84) into shape (83)
```

Changing the dimension of the initialized array somehow changes the dimensions of my already pre-made array that needs to be put into the big 2D-array structure.

I really tried circumventing this problem using every possible function I could find, including reshaping, appending, concatenating, stacking, ...

It would be a massive help if there would be a solution to this problem/ an easier way to take the values out of a list of dictionaries and putting them into a numpy array.

Full code: 
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd
    from collections import Counter
    import torch
    from torch import autograd, nn

```
X = pd.read_csv('PromoterTrain.csv', index_col=0).values.tolist()
y = pd.read_csv('SigmaTrain.csv', index_col=0).values.tolist()

def reverse_complement(dna):
        complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
        return ''.join([complement[base] for base in dna[::-1]])

X = [''.join(x) for x in X]    
X_comp = [reverse_complement(X[i]) for i in range(0,len(X))] 
kmer_1 = ['A','T','G','C']
kmer_2 = ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TA', 'TT', 'TG', 'TC', 'GA', 'GT', 'GG', 
'GC', 'CA', 'CT', 'CG', 'CC']
kmer_3 = ['AAA', 'AAT', 'AAG', 'AAC', 'ATA', 'ATT', 'ATG', 'ATC', 'AGA', 
'AGT', 'AGG', 'AGC', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'ACG', 'ACC', 'TAA', 'TAT', 'TAG', 'TAC', 
'TTA', 'TTT', 'TTG', 'TTC', 'TGA', 'TGT', 'TGG', 'TGC', 'TCA', 'TCT', 'TCG', 
'TCC', 'GAA', 'GAT', 'GAG', 'GAC', 'GTA', 'GTT', 'GTG', 'GTC', 'GGA', 'GGT', 
'GGG', 'GGC', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GCG', 'GCC', 'CAA', 'CAT', 'CAG', 'CAC', 'CTA', 
'CTT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CGG', 'CGC', 'CCA', 'CCT', 'CCG', 'CCC']

inputs_default = {'A':0,'T':0,'G':0,'C':0}
for i in range(0,len(kmer_2)-1):
        inputs_default[kmer_2[i]] = 0
for i in range(0,len(kmer_3)-1):
        inputs_default[kmer_3[i]] = 0

def count_kmers(seq, K):
        return Counter(seq[start:start+K] for start in range(len(seq) - K))

inputs_dict = []
combined_1mers = {}
combined_2mers = {}
combined_3mers = {}
combined_1mers_revcomp = {}
combined_2mers_revcomp = {}
combined_3mers_revcomp = {}

for i in range(0,len(X)-1):
    combined_1mers = count_kmers(X[i],1)
    combined_2mers = count_kmers(X[i],2)
    combined_3mers = count_kmers(X[i],3)
    combined_1mers_revcomp = count_kmers(X_comp[i],1)
    combined_2mers_revcomp = count_kmers(X_comp[i],2)
    combined_3mers_revcomp = count_kmers(X_comp[i],3)    
    combined_kmers_forward = 
{**combined_1mers,**combined_2mers,**combined_3mers}
    combined_kmers_revcomp = 
{**combined_1mers_revcomp,**combined_2mers_revcomp,**combined_3mers_revcomp}
    combined_kmers = dict((n, combined_kmers_forward.get(n, 
0)+combined_kmers_revcomp.get(n, 0)) for n in 
set(combined_kmers_forward)|set(combined_kmers_revcomp))
    inputs_dict.append(dict((n, inputs_default.get

input_array = np.zeros([len(X),84])
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    input_array[i,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict[i].values()))
```

the output for inputs_dict[0:2] gives:

```
[{'A': 28,
  'AA': 10,
  'AAA': 3,
  'AAC': 3,
  'AAG': 3,
  'AAT': 1,
  'AC': 6,
  'ACA': 2,
  'ACC': 0,
  'ACG': 2,
  'ACT': 2,
  'AG': 4,
  'AGA': 1,
  'AGC': 0,
  'AGG': 1,
  'AGT': 2,
  'AT': 8,
  'ATA': 0,
  'ATC': 4,
  'ATG': 3,
  'ATT': 1,
  'C': 22,
  'CA': 9,
  'CAA': 3,
  'CAC': 2,
  'CAG': 1,
  'CAT': 3,
  'CC': 2,
  'CCA': 1,
  'CCG': 0,
  'CCT': 1,
  'CG': 6,
  'CGA': 1,
  'CGC': 3,
  'CGG': 0,
  'CGT': 2,
  'CT': 4,
  'CTA': 0,
  'CTC': 0,
  'CTG': 1,
  'CTT': 3,
  'G': 21,
  'GA': 7,
  'GAA': 3,
  'GAC': 0,
  'GAG': 0,
  'GAT': 4,
  'GC': 6,
  'GCA': 1,
  'GCC': 1,
  'GCG': 3,
  'GCT': 0,
  'GG': 2,
  'GGA': 1,
  'GGC': 1,
  'GGG': 0,
  'GGT': 0,
  'GT': 6,
  'GTA': 1,
  'GTC': 0,
  'GTG': 2,
  'GTT': 3,
  'T': 29,
  'TA': 2,
  'TAA': 1,
  'TAC': 1,
  'TAG': 0,
  'TAT': 0,
  'TC': 7,
  'TCA': 4,
  'TCC': 1,
  'TCG': 1,
  'TCT': 1,
  'TG': 9,
  'TGA': 4,
  'TGC': 2,
  'TGG': 1,
  'TGT': 2,
  'TT': 10,
  'TTA': 1,
  'TTC': 3,
  'TTG': 2,
  'TTT': 3},
 {'A': 26,
  'AA': 8,
  'AAA': 3,
  'AAC': 1,
  'AAG': 1,
  'AAT': 3,
  'AC': 4,
  'ACA': 2,
  'ACC': 1,
  'ACG': 0,
  'ACT': 1,
  'AG': 6,
  'AGA': 3,
  'AGC': 2,
  'AGG': 0,
  'AGT': 1,
  'AT': 8,
  'ATA': 1,
  'ATC': 2,
  'ATG': 2,
  'ATT': 3,
  'C': 24,
  'CA': 7,
  'CAA': 1,
  'CAC': 2,
  'CAG': 2,
  'CAT': 2,
  'CC': 4,
  'CCA': 1,
  'CCG': 2,
  'CCT': 0,
  'CG': 6,
  'CGA': 1,
  'CGC': 3,
  'CGG': 1,
  'CGT': 0,
  'CT': 6,
  'CTA': 0,
  'CTC': 3,
  'CTG': 2,
  'CTT': 1,
  'G': 23,
  'GA': 7,
  'GAA': 2,
  'GAC': 0,
  'GAG': 3,
  'GAT': 2,
  'GC': 8,
  'GCA': 2,
  'GCC': 1,
  'GCG': 3,
  'GCT': 2,
  'GG': 3,
  'GGA': 1,
  'GGC': 1,
  'GGG': 0,
  'GGT': 1,
  'GT': 4,
  'GTA': 1,
  'GTC': 0,
  'GTG': 2,
  'GTT': 1,
  'T': 27,
  'TA': 4,
  'TAA': 2,
  'TAC': 1,
  'TAG': 0,
  'TAT': 1,
  'TC': 7,
  'TCA': 2,
  'TCC': 1,
  'TCG': 1,
  'TCT': 3,
  'TG': 8,
  'TGA': 2,
  'TGC': 2,
  'TGG': 2,
  'TGT': 2,
  'TT': 8,
  'TTA': 2,
  'TTC': 2,
  'TTG': 1,
  'TTT': 3}]
```

Comment: What's in `inputs_dict`? Could you give a sample of that object?

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: my guess is that one dicts element has 84 terms and another has 83.  Make sure you understand the source.

Comment: @alvas the output for inputs_dict[0:1] has been added to the main question block, seeing that the output is quite large and doesn't fit into a single comment

Comment: If you're doing gene sequencing and all keys in the `input_dicts` are the same you should vectorize them properly -_- ...

Comment: Can you give an example of a couple of rows from `PromoterTrain.csv` and `SigmaTrain.csv`? Are they from https://www.kaggle.com/c/promoter-site-prediction/data?

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Check what's inside your `inputs_dict` object.

---

## In Long

When you use `np.zeros([x, y])` it returns a matrix of x rows and y columns filled with zero values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros([3,10])
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> np.zeros([3,10]).shape
(3, 10)
```

When you use `range(x, y)`, it will return a list starting for x and ending at y-1:

```
>>> list(range(0, 3))
[0, 1, 2]
```

And doing this would overwrite a row of the numpy array with a list of floats:

```
numpy_array[i,:] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Initially:

```
>>> inputs = np.zeros([3,10])

>>> inputs[0,:]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> inputs[1,:]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> inputs[2,:]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

>>> inputs
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Overwriting a row:

```
>>> inputs = np.zeros([3,10])

>>> inputs[0,:] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>> inputs[0,:]
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

>>> inputs
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

As long as the left and right side of `inputs[i,:] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is the same size, it should overwrite the row successfully. Otherwise you'll find the same error in your question.

```
>>> inputs[1,:] = [0,1,2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 10
```

Going back to your code, to know what's wrong you have to check the size of the right hand side of `input_array[i,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict[i].values()))` and see whether it's the same shape.

---

Lets say you have the `input_dicts` object looking like this:

```
>>> inputs_dict = {'even-values': {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20}}
```

And you want to fit it into the left hand slide of `input_array[i,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict[i].values()))`:

```
>>> inputs = np.zeros([3,10])
>>> inputs[1,:]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
# Check the shape of left-side.
>>> inputs[1,:].shape 
(10,)


>>> inputs_dict = {'even-values': {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20}}
>>> inputs_dict['even-values'].values()
dict_values([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])
>>> np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values()))
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])

# Check shape of right-side.
>>> np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values())).shape 


# Voila, it fits:
>>> inputs[1,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values()))
>>> inputs
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.,  12.,  14.,  16.,  18.,  20.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Now if we have the no. of values in the `inputs_dict['even-values']` not fitting the same of the left-side you'll encounter the error in your question:

```
>>> inputs = np.zeros([3,10])

>>> inputs_dict = {'even-values': {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14}}

>>> np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values()))
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14])

# Right-side shape.
>>> np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values())).shape
(7,)

# Left-side shape.
>>> inputs[1,:].shape
(10,)

>>> inputs[1,:] = np.array(list(inputs_dict['even-values'].values()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7) into shape (10)
```

---

## Data structures

There are many ways to structure your data and from the looks of what's in `input_dicts`, it looks like a genetic sequence counter.

There's not really a right/wrong way to structure your data but there's always a better way.

Looking at the latest edits to your questions, you've posted:

```
>>> input_dicts = [{'CGC': 3, 'T': 29, 'GTT': 3, 'AGG': 1, 'GGG': 0, 'ATG': 3, 'TA': 2, 'AAT': 1, 'TTT': 3, 'CGA': 1, 'GGT': 0, 'GTA': 1, 'ACT': 2, 'TTA': 1, 'CAA': 3, 'CG': 6, 'GCA': 1, 'TAG': 0, 'AA': 10, 'C': 22, 'AGT': 2, 'GAG': 0, 'ATC': 4, 'CTA': 0, 'GA': 7, 'AAG': 3, 'GAT': 4, 'AGC': 0, 'CTT': 3, 'CAG': 1, 'TGA': 4, 'AAA': 3, 'CCT': 1, 'GAC': 0, 'ATT': 1, 'A': 28, 'GTC': 0, 'CTC': 0, 'TTC': 3, 'CAC': 2, 'AT': 8, 'CA': 9, 'TGC': 2, 'TGT': 2, 'GC': 6, 'TAT': 0, 'G': 21, 'CCA': 1, 'ATA': 0, 'TC': 7, 'TCC': 1, 'TGG': 1, 'CAT': 3, 'AGA': 1, 'AC': 6, 'TT': 10, 'TCA': 4, 'GCC': 1, 'ACG': 2, 'TAA': 1, 'GTG': 2, 'TG': 9, 'CTG': 1, 'CGG': 0, 'GAA': 3, 'GGC': 1, 'CCG': 0, 'TTG': 2, 'AG': 4, 'TCT': 1, 'GT': 6, 'ACA': 2, 'GCT': 0, 'TAC': 1, 'GGA': 1, 'GG': 2, 'CC': 2, 'ACC': 0, 'CGT': 2, 'TCG': 1, 'GCG': 3, 'AAC': 3, 'CT': 4}, {'CGC': 3, 'T': 27, 'GTT': 1, 'AGG': 0, 'GGG': 0, 'ATG': 2, 'TA': 4, 'AAT': 3, 'TTT': 3, 'CGA': 1, 'GGT': 1, 'GTA': 1, 'ACT': 1, 'TTA': 2, 'CAA': 1, 'CG': 6, 'GCA': 2, 'TAG': 0, 'AA': 8, 'C': 24, 'AGT': 1, 'GAG': 3, 'ATC': 2, 'CTA': 0, 'GA': 7, 'AAG': 1, 'GAT': 2, 'AGC': 2, 'CTT': 1, 'CAG': 2, 'TGA': 2, 'AAA': 3, 'CCT': 0, 'GAC': 0, 'ATT': 3, 'A': 26, 'GTC': 0, 'CTC': 3, 'TTC': 2, 'CAC': 2, 'AT': 8, 'CA': 7, 'TGC': 2, 'TGT': 2, 'GC': 8, 'TAT': 1, 'G': 23, 'CCA': 1, 'ATA': 1, 'TC': 7, 'TCC': 1, 'TGG': 2, 'CAT': 2, 'AGA': 3, 'AC': 4, 'TT': 8, 'TCA': 2, 'GCC': 1, 'ACG': 0, 'TAA': 2, 'GTG': 2, 'TG': 8, 'CTG': 2, 'CGG': 1, 'GAA': 2, 'GGC': 1, 'CCG': 2, 'TTG': 1, 'AG': 6, 'TCT': 3, 'GT': 4, 'ACA': 2, 'GCT': 2, 'TAC': 1, 'GGA': 1, 'GG': 3, 'CC': 4, 'ACC': 1, 'CGT': 0, 'TCG': 1, 'GCG': 3, 'AAC': 1, 'CT': 6}]
```

If you look carefully, you only have 83 elements in each inner dictionary key-value pairs:

```
>>> len(input_dicts[0].keys())
83

>>> len(input_dicts[1].keys())
83
```

**So naturally, when you try to overwrite the `input_array[i,:]` which is a 1x84 size array with a 1x83 array, it throws a value error.**

There are ways to pad the array to become the shape you need

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3])

>>> pad_left_column = 3
>>> pad_right_column = 2
>>> pad_top_row = 4
>>> pad_bottom_row = 5

>>> np.pad(x, [(pad_left_column, pad_right_column)], mode='constant')
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

but I would advise against that since usually the order of the columns have some meaning and simply padding zeros to make the shape correct might not be desirable.

Comment: np.array(list(inputs_dict[0].values())).shape for example gives an output of (83,) as should be expected. Yet when changing the initialized array to accommodate this size of array that will be put in, the error is given that the shape is (84,), which defies any programming logic, seeing that the dictionary, nor the array made using it is changed in any way, shape or form...

Comment: great answer alavs :)